# DevExpress treelist databound before pageload

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, treelist

i want to databind() before pageload() event.i use ondatabound() for aspx treelist to databind.But this event working after pageload()

Comment: Do you know other events except pageload ? like the `Init` ?

Comment: yes i know that events.When i try to run onpreload event  this event run first  and databound event second.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind your control in the Page_Init event handler each time a page loads?